# How to add space between images in navbar?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, menu, navbar, spacing

Can't align navbar images properly. Using bootstrap. Tried many times. Here's my code and pic of my page.

```
 <body>
  <header id="header" class="fixed-top">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-img navigation-wrap">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo lahore">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/TOL Logo-Black@2x.png"></a>
            </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#services"><img 
              src="img/navbar/SERVICES.png"></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#lahore"><img src="img/navbar/LAHORE.png"> 
               </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#menu"><img src="img/navbar/JOIN OUR 
             TEAM.png"></a>
              </li>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#contact_us"><img src="img/navbar/CONTACT 
             US.png"></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
  </header>
  </body>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHL46.jpg) - this is my code

Below attached another page how it's supposed to look like.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4LAX.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use container-fluid text-center